# Using Chebyshev's inequality on $X$ to inform distribution on $X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

By Chebyshev's inequality it is known that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu|<k\sigma\right) \geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}\,.$$
Then does it follow that
$$\mathbb{P}\left((\mu-k\sigma)^2 \leq X^2 \leq (\mu +k\sigma)^2\right) \geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$$
assuming $\mu > k\sigma$?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Irna.  What do the rules of algebra tell you?  Have you considered plugging in some simple values for $\mu,$ $\sigma,$ and $k$ to check?  Try a negative value for $\mu$ :-).

Comment: Hi Whuber, my intuition tells me yes - if $f$ is a monotonically increasing function and $1-1/k^2$ elements take on values $x \in [L, U]$, then those same elements will satisfy $f(x) \in [f(L), f(U)]$. In this case $f(x) = x^2$. I’m wondering if my intuition is correct.

Comment: Don't use intuition: use mathematics.

Comment: Yikes. Square rooting the second inequality gives the first one. This is not a good first impression I’m making on this forum.

Comment: Re "Yikes:" Try again.  When you take a square root, you have to take *both* roots -- the positive and the negative.  This isn't really a statistical question, but I'm trying to be helpful while enabling you to really understand where the mistake is.  I can tell you haven't followed my initial simple advice to plug in a few values, because then you wouldn't be wasting your time complaining: you would already have your answer.  (I see, now, that you have twice modified your question!)

Comment: Okay so we have $|\mu- k\sigma| < |X| < |\mu + k\sigma|$ and since we know $X>0$ and $\mu>k\sigma$, we can drop the absolute values, simplifying the inequality to be equal to the first one. I should’ve noted that in my problem $X>0$.

Comment: Okay, I will plug some numbers in for you.  Suppose $X$ has a $1/2$ chance to equal $1$ and a $1/2$ chance to equal $3,$ so that $\mu=2$ and $\sigma=1.$  Let $k = 6$ so that $(\mu-k\sigma)^2=(2-(6)(1))^2= 16.$ Thus, $\Pr((\mu-k\sigma)^2\le X^2)=0.$

Comment: I am curious about the original problem where you are using this inequality.

Comment: I'm trying to provide a lower bound for $\mathbb{P}\left(X^2 >Y\right)$ where $X$, $Y$ are independent random variables whose mean and variance I know. Somewhere along the way, I need the claim above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the graph of $|X-\mu|$ which is like a triangle, and the graph of $k\sigma$ which is like a straight line. In the example image below we use $k=3$

[image: example of the two graphs together]

The inequality

$$|X-\mu| < k\sigma$$

translates into $$\mu-k\sigma <X < \mu+k\sigma$$

If you take the square (which is a [non-injective](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection), ie. many-to-one or non-invertible, function) then this covers *two* regions because the cases $\mu-k\sigma <-X < \mu+k\sigma$ will also satisfy the squared inequality.

So, if $\mu > k\sigma$ then

$$\mathbb{P}\left((\mu-k\sigma)^2 < X^2 < (\mu +k\sigma)^2\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\mu-k\sigma < -X < \mu +k\sigma \right) +\mathbb{P}\left(\mu-k\sigma < X < \mu +k\sigma \right)  \geq \mathbb{P}\left(\mu-k\sigma < X < \mu +k\sigma \right) = \mathbb{P}\left(|X-\mu|<k\sigma\right) \geq 1-\frac{1}{k^2}$$

If $X>0$ then the inequality in the middle becomes an equality.

Comment: This derivation strongly depends on $\mu > k\sigma$ which ensures that both bounds $\mu-k\sigma$ and $\mu+k\sigma$ are positive. If the lower bound $\mu-k\sigma$ is negative, then the region also contains points like $X=0$, and these will 'dissapear' when you square all terms. You will have to use instead $$\mathbb{P}\left(0 < X^2 < (\mu +k\sigma)^2\right) $$